# My Windows has been installed in EFI mode?

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, uefi

I'm trying to do a dual-boot system in my new Dell Inspiron. It came with preinstalled Windows 8 and I want to install Ubuntu.

[The documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Case_when_Ubuntu_must_be_installed_in_EFI_mode) says that if my Windows installation is in EFI mode then I need to also install Ubuntu in EFI mode.

Here is my BIOS setup:

[image: setup]

Looking at the image, I suspect the Windows has been installed in EFI* mode. Am I correct?

* EFI == UEFI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be correct. The other way to check is if the drive windows is on uses a GPT partition table; windows only supports GPT partition table in EFI/UEFI boot, and in EFI/UEFI boot it also happens to only support GPT partition table. (With linux you can mix and match)